# Snackbar's action Gravity

Tags: android, android-design-library, snackbar

I'd like to display a Snackbar in my Activity. It works fine on my phone (Oneplus One CM13), however for some reason on the tablet (Nexus 7 2013 LineageOS 14.1 android 7.1.1) the action `Button` is displayed right after the Snackbar's text `TextView` (with some padding and margins).

Phone:
[image: Phone]

Tablet:
[image: Tablet]

After turning `Show layout bounds` on, I've noticed that on the phone the `TextView` takes up the whole remaining space (which makes sense), and on the tablet it just wraps it's content with about 16dp of margin on the right.

Phone with layout bounds:
[image: Phone with layout bounds]

Tablet with layout bounds:
[image: Tablet with layout bounds]

I've tried to change the `Gravity` of the action `Button` using the `LayoutParams` but it didn't work. I didn't modify the Snackbar in any way (except when trying to fix the problem). The Activity is a freshly created Empty Activity using Android Studio 2.3.

EDIT: 
Here's the full XML layout (fully generated by Android Studio):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.roundel.csgodashboard.ui.activity.SnackbarTestActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share you layout?

Comment: I've edited the question with full layout

Comment: How are you adding the TextViews/Snackbar (programmatically or another xml) and populating them?

Comment: I'm using the standard way of showing a Snackbar ```Snackbar.make(v, "Test", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction(...).show();```, where v is the FAB

Comment: i would use the activity or fragment as v, not the FAB

Comment: Snackbar is not a Toast, you pass a `View` into it, it will then traverse the view tree trying to find a CoordinatorLayout. Look at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html)